# Cake PHP login for admin and member

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Helo...
i'm new in cakephp,

i want to create 2 login form, 1 for admin (for backend) and the other 1 for member (in frontend),
how to create a defferent auth and route for that?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create two login forms. You can do it with one (you can still create two forms if you really really want it).

Have a look at prefix routing : http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing

Also look at the Auth component for authentication : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

If your website has only 2 levels, it's better to use Auth component and permission checking on a method by method basis using the `isAuthorized()` method.